# Android listview OnItemClickListener getting -1

Tags: android

when i am clicking on listview item i am getting item position as -1. This is my code.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int index = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();

                System.out.println("benbenarji:"+index);

 }
        });
```

Comment: and position return -1 ?

Comment: dude... but you already have the `int position`, why you calling `getSelectedItemPosition`

Comment: then how i need to call. to get position of item selected. i am getting -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value `-1` is for [INVALID_POSITION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#INVALID_POSITION), this means there is no selection on the list. You can use `position` from on `onItemClick` to learn which item was clicked.

Comment: how to call the method.

Comment: no method. `position` is the third parameter of `onItemClick`